# JavaScript scroll 80-90%

Tags: javascript, scroll, addeventlistener

I'm trying to realize scrolling on my front page. And I want that after the user has scrolled 80-90% of the page (from top to bottom) he could observe the block ("div") with some information. I tried to do it, but my version is not correct. Could you tell me how to do it?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(form) {
                if (document.body.scrollHeight * 0.7 < document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
                    this.showForm(form);
                }
            }, this, form);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
const element = document.querySelector('.selector');

function onScroll(event) {
  const current = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  const maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;

  // if current position is more than 80% of document height
  if (current > maxHeight * 0.8) {
    element.addClass('is-active');
  } else {
    element.removeClass('is-active');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', event => onScroll(event));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
  //check the position and add the content
}
```

Instead of using windows.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

```
function onScrollShowDiv() {
    var element = document.querySelector('.selector');

    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > document.body.scrollHeight * 0.8) {
        element.classList.add('is-active');
    } else {
        element.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollShowDiv);
```

CSS :

```
.element { display:none;}
.is-active {display:block;}
```